# Change the values of the 2nd column when a user clicks on the heading of the 2nd column of a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table on my page and I was wondering if it was possible to change the values of the 2nd column when a user clicks on the heading of the 2nd column.

For example,

```
-----------------------------
| 1st heading | 2nd heading |      
|-------------|-------------|           
|             |             |
|             |             |
|             |             |
|             |             |
|             |             |
```

Now when the user clicks on "2nd heading" the value of the second column will change and the name of the heading will change too ( from 2nd heading to 3rd heading )

Comment: are you using plain vanilla javascript for this?

Comment: This is a bit too broad. Please provide code or at least library (if any) you plan to use

Comment: @Luke Becker no

Comment: I am not using any javascript library

Comment: @JoeRobert So "yes", you're using plain vanilla javascript  ;)

Comment: I dont really know what you mean by plain vanilla javascript lol!..i thought it was a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple task using jquery. 
First add id to the columns. The second heading column should be like this

**Without jQuery**

```
<th id="th2" onclick="changeVal()">2nd Heading</th>

    <script>
    function changeVal() {
    document.getElementById("th2").innerHTML = "3rd Heading";
    }
    </script>
```

**With jQuery**
This section has been updated. I added a data-state attribute the column head, so when you toggle values it will record the last change.

```
 <th id="th2" data-state="2">2nd Heading</th>
```

Add jquery code like this after linking a jquery file

```
<script type="javascript" src="path_to_jquery.js" />
 <script>
    $("#th2").click(function() {
    var state = $(this).attr("data-state");

    if(state=="2") {
    $(this).html("3rd Heading");
    $(this).attr("data-state", "3");
    } else if(state=="3") {
    $(this).html("2nd Heading");
    $(this).attr("data-state", "2");
    }
    });

//you can replace $(this) with $("#th2") or thr id of another element or table cell to manipulate the value inside
</script>
```

Try it out and give feedback

Comment: @JoeRobert > I am not using any javascript library

Comment: You need code for plain old js? Who in the world is not using jquery? Simplify your task man.

Comment: Checkout the code update. I included implementation with plain javascript

Comment: @PrinceTegaton I am using your jQuery method and I have 2 questions: 1- How can I enter the new values for the "3rd Heading". 2- It doesn't revert back to the original value. For example, after clicking the "2nd Heading" it does change to "3rd Heading" but i cant then change it back to "2nd Heading"..Thanks!

Comment: Where do you wish to click to revert to original value?

Comment: On the same heading..Like when I click on 2nd heading it changes to 3rd heading and when I click 3rd heading again it changes back to 2nd heading.

Comment: There you go. Check out the updated code and marl as answer if it works for you cos definitely it should. Good luck

Comment: @PrinceTegaton It is working perfectly!..Last thing, how can I add different values to the 3rd heading?

Comment: You just have to manipulate the code to your favor. Follow the same pattern as shown in the code. Rollup your sleeve and dig in. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example with jQuery. Maybe it will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table th:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
         $(this).text("3rd heading");
         $("tr td:nth-child(2)").text("changed");
    });
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1st heading </th> <th>2nd heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val1</td><td>val2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val1</td><td>val2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't revert back to the original value

Answer (score 0):

Add a event listener on each `th` elements and add change the `innerHTML` as you want.

The `int` value is, for now, just based on the `th` index so it will change only once (`index + 1`).
We need more informations to change the logic.

```js
var ths = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i = 0; i < ths.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    ths[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
      changeText(i);
    });
  }(i));
}

function changeText(index) {
  ths[index].innerHTML = "TH" + ( index + 1 );
  tds[index].innerHTML = "TD" + ( index + 1 );
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>TH0</th>
    <th>TH1</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TD0</td>
      <td>TD1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of argument (**I would never recommend to do it like this - javascript is there for some reason!**), here is a solution with pure CSS - though it is a hack using `checkbox` and `label` to simulate the *CSS click* and changing the content that is already hidden in the table - see demo below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}
.hide{
  display: none;
}

#h1:checked ~ table > tbody > tr > td[data-attr='h1'] span.new {
  display: block;
}
#h1:checked ~ table > tbody > tr > td[data-attr='h1'] span.new + span{
  display: none;
}

#h2:checked ~ table > tbody > tr > td[data-attr='h2'] span.new {
  display: block;
}

#h2:checked ~ table > tbody > tr > td[data-attr='h2'] span.new + span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="h1" class="hide"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="h2" class="hide"/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <label for="h1">Heading 1</label>
      </th>
      <th>
        <label for="h2">Heading 2</label>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-attr="h1">
        <span class="new hide">New Content 1</span>
        <span>Content 1</span>
      </td>
      <td data-attr="h2">
        <span class="new hide">New Content 2</span>
        <span>Content 2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-attr="h1">
        <span class="new hide">New Content 1</span>
        <span>Content 1</span>
      </td>
      <td data-attr="h2">
        <span class="new hide">New Content 2</span>
        <span>Content 2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Simple and works like a charm!..Is it possible to change the name of the heading too?

Comment: yes it can be done... One thing though - this answer works, but I won't recommend this - better to go with a javascript solution...